# Get information out of large JSON file

Tags: json, dictionary

I am new to JSON file and i'm strugeling to get any information out of it.
The structure of the JSON file is as following:

[Json file Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XitBF.png)

Now what I need is to access the "batches", to get the data from each variable.

I did try codes (shown below) i've found to reach deeper keys but somehow i still didnt get any results.

1.

```
def safeget(dct, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            dct = dct[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None
    return dct
safeget(mydata,"batches")
```

2. 

```
def dict_depth(mydata):
if isinstance(mydata, dict):
      
    return 1 + (max(map(dict_depth, mydata.values()))
                                if mydata else 0)
      
return 0
```

print(dict_depth(mydata))

The final goal then would be to create a loop to extract all the information but thats something for the future.

Any help is highly appreciated, also any recommendations how i should ask things here in the future to get the best answers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you simply want to extract all the data without any ordering?

Then this should work out:

```
# Python program to read
# json file


import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json',)

# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data['emp_details']:
    print(i)

# Closing file
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I dont really need them ordered as i have to exctract each variable within the "batch step by step anyways. Regarding your code, I think this could work, i still have to figure it out and try to convert the output in a table to double check it but i have to do this tomorrow. And just to be clear, "emp_details" can be substitutet for any "key" or does it target a certain level?

Comment: emp_details is like the array variable in the json file (like this: emp_details [...]) where the employer informations are stored in. With that for loop you iterate through all of the data in "emp_details" and just simply print them out with "print(i)". To answer your question, yes, it does target a certain key in the json file.